# A super human "spy", tracking down an alien on Earth

Tags: story-identification, aliens

I'm trying to identify a novel or novella that I read sometime before the 1980's. The key plot point was that a superhuman "government agent" was trying to capture an alien whose name was "Snipe"(?).

The super-spy had been "*modified*" and was one of a pair of twins (where his twin had numerous congenital deformities).

The alien had landed on Earth and was very violent, but from his perspective, was very honorable.

Comment: `Many years ago`? When exactly? In what language, medium, country? Take a look at the checklist [here](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question).

Comment: English.Read dureing the 70's or earlier

Comment: Great. Now you can add this to the question body.

Comment: Was this novel-length? Short story? Novelette? Doorstopper?

Comment: I remember this story.  From what I recall of the style I thought it might be by John Brunner or perhaps Mack Reynolds, but I can't place it at the moment.  The alien was hyper-intelligent but very superstitious.  He believed that humans were too primitive to have developed our level of technology and was trying to make contact with our (hypothetical) rulers.  He killed and ate people, but only because that was good manners in his society.

Answer (score 10):

The story you describe sounds like [Earth Invader](http://zenoagency.com/news/out-today-new-sf-gateway-editions-for-randall-garrett/) by Randall Garrett.  The alien was called the Nipe, was superfast and had odd funeral customs in that it felt the honorable thing was to immediately eat a defeated adversary.  A line I remember from the book:

*If I must kill you, I myself will do the honors.  You will not go uneaten.*

Comment: I concur with the identification. I've read the book published in Italy under the pen name (anagrammed) of *Darrel T. Langart*. http://www.mondourania.com/urania/u661-680/urania668.htm

Comment: It was serialized in Analog in the early 1960s. The "Anything You Can Do..." title is the most common. It was published in the US in 1969 as "Anything..." and then republished as "Earth Invader" in 1982.

Answer (score 1):

Anything You Can Do by Randall Garret. It is possible there was an alternate title but “Anything You Can Do” is the only title of which i am aware. Great novel. It may have been published as both a novella and a full length novel.

Comment: Welcome to the Science Fiction and Fantasy Stack. Please take a [tour] and visit the [help] for more information on this Stack and what we do here. Stack Exchange sites value answers that explain why the answerer thinks this is the correct answer. Your answer is an alternate title to the answer above, so might be better as a comment.